# TensorFlow1.15, multi-GPU-1-machine, how to set batch_size?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, bert, transformer

The input function code:

```
    def input_fn(params):
        """The actual input function."""
        batch_size = FLAGS.train_batch_size

        name_to_features = {
            "input_ids":
                tf.FixedLenFeature([max_seq_length], tf.int64),
            "input_mask":
                tf.FixedLenFeature([max_seq_length], tf.int64),
            "segment_ids":
                tf.FixedLenFeature([max_seq_length], tf.int64),
            "masked_lm_positions":
                tf.FixedLenFeature([max_predictions_per_seq], tf.int64),
            "masked_lm_ids":
                tf.FixedLenFeature([max_predictions_per_seq], tf.int64),
            "masked_lm_weights":
                tf.FixedLenFeature([max_predictions_per_seq], tf.float32),
            "next_sentence_labels":
                tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64),
        }

        # For training, we want a lot of parallel reading and shuffling.
        # For eval, we want no shuffling and parallel reading doesn't matter.
        if is_training:
            d = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.constant(input_files))
            d = d.repeat()
            d = d.shuffle(buffer_size=len(input_files))

            # `cycle_length` is the number of parallel files that get read.
            cycle_length = min(num_cpu_threads, len(input_files))

            # `sloppy` mode means that the interleaving is not exact. This adds
            # even more randomness to the training pipeline.
            d = d.apply(
                tf.contrib.data.parallel_interleave(
                    tf.data.TFRecordDataset,
                    sloppy=is_training,
                    cycle_length=cycle_length))
            d = d.shuffle(buffer_size=100)
        else:
            d = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(input_files)
            # Since we evaluate for a fixed number of steps we don't want to encounter
            # out-of-range exceptions.
            d = d.repeat()

        # We must `drop_remainder` on training because the TPU requires fixed
        # size dimensions. For eval, we assume we are evaluating on the CPU or GPU
        # and we *don't* want to drop the remainder, otherwise we wont cover
        # every sample.
        d = d.apply(
            tf.contrib.data.map_and_batch(
                lambda record: _decode_record(record, name_to_features),
                batch_size=batch_size,
                num_parallel_batches=num_cpu_threads,
                drop_remainder=True))
        d = d.prefetch(10)
        return d
```

The mirrow strategy code:

```
    distribution = tf.contrib.distribute.MirroredStrategy(
        devices=["device:GPU:%d" % i for i in range(FLAGS.n_gpus)],
        # num_gpus=4,
        cross_tower_ops=tf.distribute.HierarchicalCopyAllReduce())
    run_config = RunConfig(
        train_distribute=distribution,
        # eval_distribute=dist_strategy,
        log_step_count_steps=log_every_n_steps,
        model_dir=FLAGS.output_dir,
        save_checkpoints_steps=FLAGS.save_checkpoints_steps)

    model_fn = model_fn_builder(
        bert_config=bert_config,
        init_checkpoint=FLAGS.init_checkpoint,
        learning_rate=FLAGS.learning_rate,
        num_train_steps=FLAGS.num_train_steps,
        num_warmup_steps=FLAGS.num_warmup_steps,
        use_tpu=FLAGS.use_tpu,
        use_one_hot_embeddings=FLAGS.use_tpu)

    # If TPU is not available, this will fall back to normal Estimator on CPU
    # or GPU.
    estimator = Estimator(
        model_fn=model_fn,
        params={},
        config=run_config)
```

The problem is that if I have 4 GPU. Each GPU could run 8 batchsize. I set `batch_size = 8` not 32. `batch_size = 32` will OOM.

Am I right? Will the data be distributed to 4 GPU with different batches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [BERT-GPU](https://github.com/guotong1988/BERT-GPU/blob/master/run_pretraining_gpu_v2.py).

No problem with the code.

The `batch_size` is for 1 GPU.

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow handles batches differently on distribution strategies if you're using Keras, Estimator, or custom training loops.

Since you are using TF1.15 Estimator with MirroredStrategy in one worker (1 machine), each replica (one per GPU) will receive a batch size of `FLAGS.train_batch_size`. So, if you have 4 GPUs, then the global batch size will be `4 * FLAGS.train_batch_size`.

Here's the explanation:

> In Estimator, however, the user provides an input_fn and have full control over how they want their data to be distributed across workers and devices. We do not do automatic splitting of batch, nor automatically shard the data across different workers. The provided input_fn is called once per worker, thus giving one dataset per worker. Then one batch from that dataset is fed to one replica on that worker, thereby consuming N batches for N replicas on 1 worker. In other words, the dataset returned by the input_fn should provide batches of size PER_REPLICA_BATCH_SIZE. And the global batch size for a step can be obtained as PER_REPLICA_BATCH_SIZE * strategy.num_replicas_in_sync.

Source: [TF1.X Distribution Strategy Notebook](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r1/guide/distribute_strategy.ipynb)